# Identify an '80s/'90s animated film from a scene

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am trying to identify an animated film (or TV series episode) that I watched on TV when I was a child:

- I watched it some time in the early '90s - adding the usual propagation delay for foreign shows in my country (Greece) at the time, it was probably created in the '80s.
- Classic 2-D animation artwork, fairly detailed. Probably created by hand; didn't feel at all like CGI.
- It was sci-fi themed and rather dark, both in plot and presentation. In retrospect, it was probably unsuitable for my age but TV program managers back then still thought that "animated" equals "for children".
- Some of the characters had a power of some sort similar to the Force Lightning from Star Wars, although I believe the lightning color was more white/yellow than blue.
- One of the main male characters was named "Lok" or "Loch" or similar. Or not; the audio was dubbed, so for all I know all the names were mangled.
- I sort-of remember one scene, probably due to all the violence:

  - It involved a robot of some sort killing the aforementioned character, after he failed to defend himself with the lightning-thingie.
  - It used retractable metallic cone-shaped (rather than flat-bladed) elements that emerged from round holes in its main body to stab the person to death.
  - I seem to remember a close-up shot of the bloodied cones immediately after the deed; two cones in a vertical arrangement emerging from the right (as seen by the viewer) front side of the robot's body.
  - I have the impression that the robot drove the cones into the person by moving its whole body; I don't remember them being able to move independently.
  - I think that the robot had a blocky main body and was possibly tracked, but I may be wrong. I am pretty sure it was not humanoid, though.

Comment: The 1981 film _Heavy Metal_ features a green orb called the Loc-Nar, but  otherwise doesn't match. But perhaps another Loc-Nar story was made.

Comment: Some of these elements line up with the "Franken Gears" segment of 1987's "Robot Carnival". The robot is brought to life with lightning (both yellow AND white), the robot is big and blocky, and the man is killed. Not with spikes, though, the robot falls on him. Lots of the elements don't match, so probably not it. Thought I'd throw it out there though.

Answer (score 2):

Might it be [Rock and Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_%26_Rule)?

[image]

"My name is Mok, thanks a Lot"

Comment: Uh, no... this looks and feels completely different to what I remember. And the whole music-style setup would have felt too silly to me; except for very rare exceptional (and memorable) cases, I'd have never been able to sit through it, even as a child. Thanks for looking for it, though!